# How to find the minimum element of a matrix of objects in java?

Tags: java, class, matrix

I have a Matrix class that has the following attributes: number of Lines, number of columns and a matrix of Objects.

I have to find the minimum element of the matrix of Objects. How could I do that if I don't know what my Objects will be in JAVA?

Comment: If you don't know what the matrix contains, I don't see how you could compare its elements. You should know what the matrix contains. Where is your code? Also, Java is spellled Java, not JAVA.

Comment: If the Objects implement Comparable, it's a go, otherwise it can't be done.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Do you have an matriix like this: `Object[][][] obj`; or this `Object[][] obj`? And do you know the size of the matrix? I'm willing to help you but as of right now I do now understand your question.

Comment: You might rewrite Matrix as Matrix<? extends Comparable> and calculate the minimum in the usual way, except for applying x,compareTo(y) rather than comparing with '<'.

Comment: I have a Object[][] obj matrix.

Comment: Can I use compareTo for two unknown Objects?

Comment: The must implement java.lang.Comparable. Otherwise, how do you think you can compare two Foos?

Comment: Simply use Comparable rahter than Object and write your class. Test with Integer or String or ...

Comment: is this part of a project for a business or academic? If business will help to hear the use case and context as much as NDA/ trade secrets allow

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the comparable or comparator functions to, effectively sort arrays of objects by a specific value. You will, depending override the compare to value and select an instance field to make comparisons with.

Comment: I understand that, but I have to compare two Objects. I don't know what the fields are.

Comment: @AnaG131: this question makes no sense. Suppose the first element of your matrix is a Socket, the second one is an Orange, and the third one is the character 'A'. Which of these is smaller or bigger than the other ones?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use reflection to find out of the objects implement comparable and are all the same type or same base type, and that base type implements Comparable.
2. if not go thru all the fields, for every field that is a string or a number, compare with corresponding... if its an object go in to that and find strings and numbers. Can make a generic comparator. If a field is a collection then poke in to the type and process similarly. Not an easy task but doable. You could also choose not to go more than x level deep by keeping a current level int that you pass around your stack (if you get in to properties that are objects)

Comment: You might as well compare the Objects' hashCode... Do you really think that any such comparison make any *sense*? - For instance: If the object contains ("ABC", 12) and another one ("XYZ", -1) - which one is bigger? And that's a relatively harmless situation... Surely you were kidding?

Comment: its the natural order. Might not make sense in all business case. But will in a lot. For example if they are product names and prices they will line up by name of product, description etc

Comment: And if the first attribute is the available stock count...? Aw, come on! And this being a matrix, and to search the minimum. - I grant you that you mean well and try and help in a helpless case.

Comment: @laune Yes it will be random across objects, but when you don't know anything what else can you do? Will be interesting to do this for a bunch of well known objects and see where it goes :-) unleash the generic comparator on code google, source forge and git!